# How do I run a command once in webViewDidFinishLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I'm finding it hard to run an alert in webViewDidFinishLoad once, the first time, when the app is opened and the webViewDidFinishLoad is finished loading. The problem being, I use a webview and it's updating frequently. I know how to make sure a command is run only once in an apps lifetime but I need the command to run specifically ONCE every time the app is loaded and it HAS TO BE in webViewDidFinishLoad. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Right now, this is the code I need to run once at the beginning of every app in the webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
[activityind stopAnimating];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Are you ready to get directions?", @"The title of an alert that tells the user, that no server was set.")
                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"Click 'LAUNCH IT' and we'll do all the work! ", @"The message of an alert that tells the user, that no server was set.")
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LAUNCH IT!", @"A common affirmative action title, like 'OK' in english.")
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                             AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

                             NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dotcom.com/In.js"];
                             NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

                             NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
                                 NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
                                 // Save this following url to load the file
                                 return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
                             } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"BLAST OFF! IN CODE HAS LANDED :)");
                             }];
                             [downloadTask resume];
                             NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];

                             [_viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];

                             NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PrivacyView" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                             [_viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
                             NSLog(@"PRIVACY VIEW!: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LAUNCH_KEY]);
                         }];
    UIAlertAction *dontshowagain = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Don't Show Again", @"A common affirmative action title, like 'OK' in english.")
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
                                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                                    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:dontshowagain];

    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st APPROACH**

Use a **BOOL instance variable** to check whether the alert has been shown already or not.

Example:

```
@implementation ViewController () {
    BOOL shownAlertOnce;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    //your code here.......
    if (shownAlertOnce == NO) {
        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        shownAlertOnce = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

**2nd APPROACH**

**Use dispatch_once**

Example:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    //your code here.......

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; 
    });
}
```

**Note:** Although 2nd approach is an easy one but take care that it should ideally be used to avoid race condition between multiple threads.

So, if your code is being accessed by a single thread, then prefer 1st approach, else 2nd.

Comment: @Creagen: It means the code is not called by multiple threads (as in the case of multi threading).

But as in your case - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView is called on main thread, so opting approach 1 is better.

Comment: Copy that. I went with approach one. Although your code didn't seem to work for me. Maybe I didn't do it properly. The code below, similar to yours seemed to work though. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: yeah my bad, there was a typo in the variable name and the condition had to be checked for a NO

Comment: No problemo. This really helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dispatch_once_t`.

> Executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an
>   application

https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once

**Example**

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the lifetime of the application during the instance that it's open? As in, if you close the app and reopen the app, it will appear only once again. But only once until you close and reopen the app. Am I understanding you correctly? :p Sorry if I am confusing!

Comment: Yes.. Until app is running. If app is killed and re started again that code will execute again.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I needed to do. Much appreciated!

Comment: As dispatch_once is synchronised, you should prefer it when the code can be accessed by multiple threads. If not then for performance improvement, one should prefer creating a BOOL property / instance member and use it to check if the alert has already been shown.
Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44236620/5237727

Comment: @SaurabhBhatia Yes you are right but questing says *ONCE every time the app is loaded* i think you have to do a bit more to achieve that behaviour with *BOOL property* method. But anyway problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: @Bilal: Yes a bit more has to be done to achieve the behaviour using BOOL property method, but as I mentioned due to synchronization dispatch_once is slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one `BOOL` property and comparing it inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    BOOL isAlertShown;
}     
@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Set isAlertShown to false
    isAlertShown = NO;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (!isAlertShown) {
        isAlertShown = YES;
        //Show alert here
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You actually don't need to set isAlertShown to No in viewDidLoad as the default value of a BOOL is NO.

Comment: I know that default value of a BOOL is false, I have specified it so that OP don't confused about it.